What cameos did Stan Lee have in the DC universe?
After retiring from Marvel, Stan Lee had a number of cameos in the Marvel Cinematic Universe. But was he in anything DC, either as a character or an actor?
Related: Was Stan Lee in the second diner scene in the movie Superman 2? The answer is no, but it does mention Teen Titans Go! to the Movies.

Stan appeared in the DC animated film, Teen Titans GO! to the Movies (2018). According to Wikipedia and NME, it was his first and only appearance in a DC film.

Stan Lee has made his first ever cameo in a DC comics movie, in the animated feature Teen Titans Go! To the Movies.
The Marvel Comics editor makes regular appearances in Marvel movies but has yet to appear in a DC Comics Universe creation – until now.
Lee appears in animated form in the Teen Titans movie during a scene which sees them visit Warner Bros Studios in Hollywood. They come across lots of famous faces while on the lot, including Lee himself.





Stan Lee has appeared quite a few times in various Marvel comics over the years. As far as I know, though, the closest he's come to having a cameo in a DC comic was when Ambush Bug mimicked his appearance during a Deadpool-esque, fourth wall-breaking moment in Suicide Squad Vol. 7 #11 (2022).

AMBUSH BUG: Look, it's not as cool as Amalgam Comics, but this should be fun!

Suicide Squad Vol. 7 #11 (March, 2022)

The plot of that issue involving the Suicide Squad visiting Earth 8, where they encountered the Retaliators, an obvious pastiche of Marvel's Avengers.
Amalgam Comics were a line of crossover stories co-published by DC and Marvel in the mid-1990s.

This may be the definitive answer for DC movies, but I'm also asking about other mediums like comics.
